# Naive Bayes for classifying columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, bayesian, text-classification

Hello StackExchange Community,

I have a unique use case for Naive Bayes where I'm trying to train my model to identify output column names based on previous data of input column names.

Basically, my data looks like this:

```
 1. Output Column  |   Input Columns  
 2. Col1        |       ABC DEF GHI 
 3. Col2        |       JKL MNO QPR
 4. Col3        |       STU VWX
```

This is historical data which indicates that

we received a data in a column named 'ABC' and we mapped the data into 'Col1'
we received a data in a column named 'DEF' and we mapped the data into 'Col1'
we received a data in a column named 'JKL' and we mapped the data into 'Col2'
and so on...

I rearranged my data as below and trained my model using Naive Bayes' text classification (similar to an email spam classifier).

```
1. Output Column   |   Input Columns
 2. Col1           |         ABC
 3. Col2           |         JKL
 4. Col3           |         STU
 5. Col1           |         DEF
 6. Col2           |         MNO
 7. Col3           |         STU
```

and so on...

For predictions, I will be providing input columns to the trained model and asking which output column class the input should belong to, along with a probability score.

Do you think my approach to solving this problem is correct? With about 100 rows of data, I've been getting accurate predictions but low probability score (~40%).

Any feedback would be appreciated here, as this ML model can help us a lot in automating tasks.

Code:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(training_data['Input Column'].values)
classifier = MultinomialNB()
targets = training_data['Output Column'].values

classifier.fit(counts, targets)

for index, row in test_data.iterrows():
    panel=row['SourcePanel']
    panel=[panel]
    example_counts = vectorizer.transform(panel)
    predictions = classifier.predict(example_counts)
    probability = classifier.predict_proba(example_counts)
    df=pd.DataFrame(classifier.predict_proba(example_counts), columns=classifier.classes_)
    print("The source panel attribute ", panel, " maps to Target entity Attribute", df[predictions], "probability")
```